# Using iptables-nft/ebtables-nft to intercept specific forwarded/bridged IP packets on a bridge and redirect them to the bridge device itself

Tags: networking, iptables, redirection, bridge, nftables

With a bridge br0 using eth0 and wlan0 as bridge ports, formerly one could intercept packets arriving on a bridge port with `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m physdev --physdev-in wlan0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 -j REDIRECT`.
Since iptables is now replaced by iptables-nft by default, using `-m physdev` doesn't work anymore.
Something like `ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i wlan0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto UDP --ip-dport 53 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP` or `ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING --logical-in br0 -p ipv4 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT` should let the packet be routed and traverse through the iptables chains.
Shouldn't it be possible to then use <strike>`iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -p UDP --destination-port 53 -j REDIRECT` or</strike> `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p UDP --destination-port 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.XXX.XXX`? 
I don't know where exactly into which iptables chain the packet gets dropped into by ebtables, the PREROUTING, INPUT or FORWARD chain. The only information about the relative chain order between iptables and ebtables chains I found was on a netfilter.org page last updated in 2003 and it doesn't mention the BROUTING chain.
I would like to avoid having to set `br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1` and therefore `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` / `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, as I would lose the IPV6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in the former case.

Comment: I believe I've seen brouting support being added to nftables among the linux.git commits literally just a week ago... but after having used a firewall that relied extensively on brouting, I can't help but consider it the most cursed networking "feature" ever added.

Comment: @user1686 I know there is probably a `nft` style command/script that replicates the functionality of the `iptables -m physdev` equivalent. My question is how to write the rule with iptables-nft and/or ebtables-nft without installing nft explicitly?

Comment: "Since iptables is now replaced by iptables-nft by default, using `-m physdev` doesn't work anymore." is just false. iptables-nft isn't iptables 100% translated into nftables. It's nftables (sortof) plus xtables extensions, like physdev, which is not usable by plain nftables. Same for the LED target (to blink actual leds): iptables-nft will use it, nftables can't.

Comment: the actual problem is that NAT is done in the nat table not the mangle table. `-t mangle ... -j REDIRECT` is thus invalid.

Comment: And I just tested the command (also using a bridged wireless since I'm  using 4addr with hostapd and wpa_supplicant): works fine by changing -t mangle with -t nat, interception works.

Comment: Now, this relies on having br_netfilter loaded and active. So your last sentence: "avoid having to set br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1" (or else not having the systemwide net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1)  is incompatible with using physdev.